# application-specific PATH variables

Tags: path, java

This might be a question without an answer, but I thought it would
be worth asking nevertheless. I've got two applications A and B
where A requires JRE 5 and B requires JRE 7 (these come with
windows and linux versions). However the application that
requires JRE 5 will not run against JRE 7. How can I run
both without having to tweak the PATH environment
variable to point to the correct java program
prior to running each of A and B based on
which of the two I need to run?

Seems like there must be a way to set application-specific PATH
variables/JREorJDK pointers.

Thanks,

Jason Posit

Comment: Give the full path to specific java application launcher `java` you need for each.

Comment: just use the full path when you're calling the java engine: `c:\jdk5.0\bin\java.exe MyJava5Class` and `c:\jdk7\bin\java.exe\MyShinyNewJava7Class`

Comment: which server are you using ?

Comment: Seems to me you guys got it. Why don't you post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the JAVA_HOME in your server startup script specific to java version you are using

This is a bit tricky, if you are trying to deploy the applications on the same server then you have to modify the start up script to take the JAVA_HOME value at startup then set the JAVA_HOME accordingly.

for JBOSS you can set the JAVA_HOME in  JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.conf

for tomcat you can set the JAVA_HOME in  CATALINA_HOME/bin/setEnv.cmd

Comment: Thanks, the answer seems to be indeed to set up a path variable in a startup script with the path alternative to the system or user path, and then execute the script by clicking on the script rather than on the application itself. This should fix the problem. Jason Posit

Answer (score 3):

Two options:  Either call the java engine from the full path depending on which one you want eg for Java 5:

`c:\jdk5\bin\java.exe` | `/usr/bin/java5/java` `MyJava5Class`

change the path accordingly for java 7.

Or you can set up Java5_Home and Java7_Home environment variables to point to the root install directory of those locations (or if you're lazy like me straight into bin\java.exe) and call the java engine using them:

`%Java5_Home%\bin\java.exe Java5Class`

or

`$Java7_Home/bin/java MyShinyNewJava7Class`